# Use sapply on column of dataframe to select return values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `terms` associated with topics using LDA:

```
Topic 1   Topic 2   Topic 3
foo1      bar1      cow1
foo2      bar2      cow2
foo3      bar3      cow3
```

In another dataframe `items`, I have a list of items linked to a topic:

```
ItemID    Topic
item1       1
item2       1
item3       2
item4       3
```

I want to create a new column `items$terms` which returns the terms associated with that topic:

```
ItemID    Topic   terms
item1       1     foo1 foo2 foo3
item2       1     foo1 foo2 foo3
item3       2     bar1 bar2 bar3
item4       3     cow1 cow2 cow3
```

I tried this:

```
items$terms <- sapply(items$Topic,paste(terms[,x],collapse = " "))

# For each item, find the topic, and return the pasted terms from topicterms
```

But I get the error:

> Error in [.data.frame(topicterms, , x) : object 'x' not found.

Can you tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: What is `topicterms` ? Probably you need `sapply(items$Topic, function(x) terms[paste("Topic", x)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot that `sapply` takes a function and not an expression as its argument:

`items$terms <- sapply(items$Topic,function(x) paste(topicterms[,x],collapse = " "))`

However, this formulation will require your column names in `topicterms` to exactly match the Topic values in `items`, which they don't right now - one is numbers and one is the string `"Topic "` with the number appended. It's probably easiest to just change the column names:

`names(topicterms) <- 1:3`

Comment: Doesn't topicterms[,3] return the third column?

Comment: If I run the expression on e.g. items$Topic[1] it works

Comment: This works, but I want to know why it didn't work when referring to column number rather than column name